# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':logrocket_react-native:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: react-native, package, build.gradle, logrocket

I installed

```
logrocket/react-native
```

and add to android/build.gradle

```
maven { url "https://storage.googleapis.com/logrocket-maven/" }
```

once all that is done i run my react native project on android but it keeps failing with this error

```
BUILD FAILED in 34s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':logrocket_react-native:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':logrocket_react-native:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.logrocket:logrocket:1.18.0.
     Required by:
         project :logrocket_react-native
```

- tried to uninstall the nodemodule
- tried to clear gradlew
- increasing the logrocket/react-native version to 1.18.0, 1.19.0,1.19.2

this should have built and could yarn android built my app.

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same issue: My `android/build.gradle` already had:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

I initially added the `maven { ... }` line from the LogRocket docs to this block. But note that the top-level key here is `buildscript`, while the LogRocket docs specify `allprojects`.

In my case, I was able to get it working by adding a whole new `allprojects` section to the end of my `build.gradle`:

```
// ...

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://storage.googleapis.com/logrocket-maven/" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could not find com.logrocket:logrocket:1.18.0

I think it means maven may not configured properly for `logrocket`.

You can try by adding the following to the android/build.gradle

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      maven { url "https://storage.googleapis.com/logrocket-maven/" }
  }
}
```

It seems it's ok to have multiple `allprojects.repositories` in the build.gradle

Comment: thanks for your answer, 
It seems that our gradle's are a bit different I have only a single repositories when i wrapped it under allprojects  and added the second repositories it don't seem to work maybe I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Can you post your allprojects section of the gradle config ?